# Upgrading react native to latest version

Tags: react-native

I have an application which runs on react-native 0.49.3
I want to upgrade to the latest version which is v0.57.4.

Should I incrementally update it? For example 0.49 -> 0.50 -> 0.51 etc
Or I can just update it to to the latest version?

Do you suggest using `react-native-git-upgrade` or `rn-diff`?

Comment: There's no mention of incremental updates on the documentation. The only thing that they mention is this: "Some upgrades require manual steps, e.g. 0.28 to 0.29, or 0.56 to 0.57. Be sure to check the release notes when upgrading so that you can identify any manual changes your particular project may require."
Took it from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading

Comment: My advise: wait with RN updates for at least half a year to give package maintainers a chance to catch up (and make your own life easy). I've had issues when updating RN in the past, now I just wait about a year, then create a new project with newer version and migrate my code... that seems to be a more simple and error prone task than updating RN in an existing project.

Answer (score 24):

My advice is to upgrade to the latest version. There will be enough dependency issues anyway so you're best dealing with them only once.

From the React Native upgrade page
(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading)

you can run:

```
npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
npm install -g @react-native-community/cli
react-native-git-upgrade
```

UPDATE 2:
The new command is

`npx react-native upgrade`

but I believe this is best for upgrading from more recent versions. If you have older versions, the following upgrade process still applies.

UPDATE:
I've never had a problem before with upgrades, but recently joined a project where we upgraded from an old copy of React Native 0.44.3 to a newer version (first to 0.57.8, then to 0.55.4, then to 0.58.3 while struggling with stability) and discovered that it's not always as easy as running those commands. Be warned that this could be a long, tedious process, especially if you have not upgraded regularly and have a long gap between upgrades. In this case, it was 18 months since they had upgraded.

First, there have been changes to the upgrade process itself (react-native upgrade, to now react-native-git-upgrade) itself. So, if you're using a version that's a year old or more there could be some manual discrepancies that you'll have to go through. Some are spelled out after running the react-native-git-upgrade command, and some are not. I was amazed at the number of people on Stack Overflow going through the same undocumented circular issues of a seemingly innocent upgrade. I was not expecting that. I'd be OK with Facebook not adding any features for 6 months and simplifying the upgrade process before moving on.

Second, make sure your version of React Native uses the right dependencies. Later versions of the upgrade tool (react-native-git-upgrade) try to account for this, but double check at https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md to see if the version of RN that you're upgrading to requires a specific dependency. Some do while others do not.

Next, library hades is real, depending on how big your project is. In our case, several modules in use in our 0.44.3 version have now been deprecated or no longer maintained or even work differently with the later versions of RN. I didn't consider this enough when starting this process. This caused several instances of code rewrite just to upgrade!! Yikes!

Also, just as some versions of React Native require specific versions of dependencies, other modules require specific versions of some dependencies. Worse, sometimes these are incompatible and conflicting versions, of various libraries. Save some time and write a user story or two to account for this. Go through every module you're using and see if there are any compatibility statements on their GitHub page. Some Readme files will tell you to use certain versions of their module with certain versions of React Native. Others won't and you may find out later there are requirements. But even going through this process and anticipating issues, you'll thank yourself later.

Once you're up to date and stable, consider upgrading regularly to minimize the upgrade nightmare that I just went through.

Comment: That is a great answer! I would add that https://github.com/pvinis/rn-diff-purge is a useful too,  as it can show you the specific changes between each version. I no longer upgrade using `react-native-git-upgrade` due to issues that I have had, but instead I just do it manually, and as you said I try to do it frequently too.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!! I appreciate the comment, and also, the purge solution sounds great but I never actually used it. I'll play around with that the next time.

Comment: I like it as it gives a nice `git diff` so you can see what has changed. Very useful for manual upgrades.

Comment: react-native-git-upgrade is officially dead.  Use rn-diff-purge to get up to RN 0.59.x, and after that use react-native upgrade.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23866#issuecomment-472086814

Comment: @lukewilliams, It's about time! Facebook really dropped the ball and made some upgrades way too difficult. I'm glad they're trying to simplify it. rn-diff-purge is a good start.

Comment: I think the new command is now npx react-native upgrade

Answer (score 16):

1. You will need [@react-native-community/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cli) to upgrade to the latest version of react-native, sadly not mentioned anywhere.

   npm install -g @react-native-community/cli
2. Install react-native-git-upgrade

   npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
3. Now go to your project.

   cd your-react-native-project
4. Now you can run the upgrade command.

   react-native upgrade

Answer (score 8):

Just change the path to the project for which you want to upgrade the react native version and then run this command:

> react-native upgrade

and after running this command you will see some questions. Type n to discard the change to that file or type y if you want to modify that file.
It will automatically install the latest version of react-native for your project.
More info at:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading

**OR**

You can upgrade react native version by this simple step:

1- Just go to package.json file of your project

2- After that, look for these lines

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
 }
```

3- Change the react-native version to any version that you want to upgrade to in `"dependencies"`.

4- After this run `npm install` and react native version will be upgraded for your project.

Comment: I'm currently on 0.57.1 and haven't been able to target upgrading to 0.59.1.  Is there some additional process I need to go through?

Comment: @Petrogad Hi! can you share your package.json react native version after running the above command? so that I can guide you further.

Comment: for me it stays at "react-native": "^0.57.1" I feel like I'm doing something goofy as all the docs seem to point towards that.  Also worth noting, when I run that command it additionally tells me to go grab the old upgrade tool, react-native-git-upgrade

Comment: I am updating my answer wait.

Comment: @Petrogad see my updated answer and try that second method.

Comment: Thank you for the update! If I go that route, won't I miss out on the various changes needed to the native side project libraries which react-native upgrade helps reconcile?

Comment: yeah probably not necessarily and if you do get any error by the second method then do update that library for the particular react native version.

Comment: @Petrogad I hope my last comment was fully understandable to you. Let me know if you need more clarification on this. Just ping me via comment here or move this discussion to chat if you need further help from me on this issue :) I will be happy to help you and dont forget to upvote the answer to help future readers.

Comment: After doing that, there are so many dependencies that need to be updated / checked.  The best thing I found was to go here: https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.0...version/0.59.1 and manually work through the additions that were needed to change.

Comment: @Petrogad Yeah! that too helps many answers claim that but for me I wasnt able to clearly get the idea on how to use that and was confused. Maybe you can edit this answer for further steps for future readers.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [this](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper) tool (upgrade helper) which allows you to compare your current react native version and latest react native version.

Also, It's good to upgrade react-native frequently to stay up to date with the latest version and make the upgrade process easy.

> https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Answer (score 4):

I recommend visiting this page: https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge

because you can see the list of exactly what changes in each version. I find it's simpler to manually change config settings after starting from your version that is proven to work properly via `react-native run-android` and `react-native run-ios`.

It sounds like a horrible task, but it's not very difficult for your fingers or brain to remove red lines and add green lines--at least compared to alternatives such as Googling to sort out horrific error messages in the Android/iOS build systems.

I also believe that it's a good idea to manually change config settings for example going from 0.44 to 0.59 because you get more of an opportunity to see exactly what is changing in each version. You'll see the changes are reasonable and generally have bearing on fostering future automation and increasing the build systems' robustness and aversion to breakage.

Additionally, changes were implemented in RN 0.59 that makes `react-native upgrade` better, and in addition to my additional statement, the whole 0.59 release is pretty massive and important for future: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/#upgrading-to-059

I'm not even going to talk about `react-native upgrade` or `react-native-git-upgrade` because I find those to be generally a source of nightmares especially if you get into `react-native unlink` and `react-native link`.

Answer (score 4):

Even with using the new upgrade helper https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ I still run into a bunch of issues and it takes forever to debug them. The best and most reliable way I have found to upgrade after react-native core teams make big changes like adding fast-refresh or flipper that involves a lot of xcode related changes it just start from scratch.

create new repo

```
npx react-native init newProject
```

STEP 1 -
make sure the new app runs properly so you know if you have an xcode/react native package issues that need to be upgraded. I know I ran into an xcode issue that forced me to upgrade to a new mac os version.

STEP 2 - pull up old projects xcworkspace or xcodeproj if you are not using any custom pods and just copy over the important stuff like the signing stuff and potentially any custom build scripts you have. I have custom fonts so I pull that over

STEP 3 - copy over app specific code, think app folder or src and any files that live in the root of your project.

STEP 4 - Run npm install and pod install if you have custom pods

STEP 5 - Important not to just paste over the App.js/tsx file but instead just render a simple view with text in it. If your app will run here then it means all your npm/pods are configured properly. Usually I run into a bunch of error in this step which require me to upgrade npm/pods to new version to deal with breaking changes in react-native

STEP 5.a - One by one add in each line from your original App.js/tsx file and testing if anything breaks. Sometimes its useful to reset your metro cache in between changes and removing the build folders inside of ios and android during debugging. Also its very helpful to use the chrome debugger stop on exception functionality here so you know where the issues are coming from

STEP 6 - copy over .git folder from previous project that lives in the root of your project so you can keep your version history or just create a new git repo if you dont care about this.

I have upgraded RN to newer versions in a couple of hours using this method multiple times. I typically write myself some notes while I do it to speed to up the process next time I need to upgrade. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

In case there are changes then you can either update them manually by copying and pasting from the changes in the page or you can do it with the React Native CLI upgrade command by running:

`npx react-native upgrade`

As explained in the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading

Answer (score 2):

You can update to the latest version directly, I'd recommend to do it with react-native-git-upgrade, but do be careful to read the update release notes on the versions up to yours, they have some notes about things you should do manually that the upgrade will not. You can find the notes here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases

The notes are usually on top in the changelogs, I know the latest releases had some of those and gave me some work to update from 0.54 recently so be aware.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 use react native update helper  [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)

Step 2 [try with this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading)

I always follow the first step to update my entire project

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to kick off the upgrade: npx @rnx-kit/align-deps --requirements react-native@[major.minor].
align-deps is an OSS tool from Microsoft that automates dependency management. It knows which packages* versions are compatible with your specific version of RN, and it uses that knowledge to align dependencies, keeping your app healthy and up-to-date**. Find out more here.

- Not all packages are supported out-of-the-box.
  ** You still need to do the other changes below and verify the changelogs of the libraries that got upgraded.

Ref: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.6&to=0.71.1

Answer (score 0):

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

Should do all the work for you.

Comment: this will not always work, especially in case of conflict. there is a web tool for checking the difference in each file. that one is highly recommended

Comment: You can check to react upgrade https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ to fix the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

use cammand npx react-native upgrade

if you are facing errors it's due to some deprecated packages.So comment all pages and in route and step by step add your pages and replace your deprecated packages with new .

And also use this update helper 'https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the steps provided by other users here, in case of manual update, try to use upgrade-helper and chatgpt to not forget any line of code.

- https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Answer (score -1):

You can Upgrade with 4 simple step

1. npm install -g @react-native-community/CLI
2. npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
3. cd your-react-native-project
4. react-native upgrade

Thanks :)