# React native upgrade path

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

We have had an app developed by a third party. Its currently on version 0.59.9 and we want to upgrade to version 0.61.5. What is the recommended way of doing this? going through each version upgrade or doing the upgrade in one go. My worry is so much has changed and it might be difficult to go through so many version in one iteration.

Thanks Nathan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading react native to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378354/upgrading-react-native-to-latest-version)

Answer (score 0):

As said on the [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading), you can run `react-native upgrade` on the project directory to upgrade his react-native version to the newest.